# TestNG detected TestNG version 7.4.0 error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, testng

I have this TestNG part :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="ShufersalMiron.Sprod.Listeners"/>
</listeners>
<test name="Test1">
<classes>
<class name="ShufersalMiron.Sprod.PA_Coupons"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
<test  name="Test2">
<classes>
<class name="ShufersalMiron.Sprod.PA_SupermeCoins"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

When I am trying to run it as a suite I get this error :

[image]

Can someone please tell me what could be wrong and how to solve it please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error might be due to conflicting dependencies.

extentreports-java version 5.0.9 (latest for now)
https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java/blob/master/pom.xml

uses `io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava`-`3.0.4` and `org.testng:testng`-`7.3.0`.

I can suggest 2 options:

1. Try to add `io.reactivex.rxjava3` dependency, since
   `NoClassDefFound` error references this.

   Maven:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava3</groupId>
       <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.4</version> 
   </dependency>
   ```

   Gradle:

   ```
   implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.4'
   ```
2. Try to use testNG `7.3.0` instead of `7.4.0`.