# How to solve "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observer"

Tags: java, selenium, maven

I am trying to run suite using testNG but I got this error :
I search some information on this issue on this site and the web
but with no success.

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observer
    at resources.ExtentReporterNG.getReportObject(ExtentReporterNG.java:14)
    at ShufersalMiron.Sprod.Listeners.<init>(Listeners.java:22)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.newInstance(InstanceCreator.java:30)
    at org.testng.TestNG.addListeners(TestNG.java:964)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeConfiguration(TestNG.java:924)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:1012)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:98)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 17 more
```

TestNG :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
    <listeners>
    <listener class-name="ShufersalMiron.Sprod.Listeners"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="Test1">
    <classes>
    <class name="ShufersalMiron.Sprod.PA_Coupons"/>
    </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
    <test  name="Test2">
    <classes>
    <class name="ShufersalMiron.Sprod.PA_SupermeCoins"/>
    </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I search for an answer in the net but with no success.

Can someone help me with this issue please ?

Comment: I see the same was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70562352/testng-detected-testng-version-7-4-0-error, have you tried any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This issue looks like not related to TestNG.

It just appeared within TestNG lifecycle, so testng is mentioned in the error.

The line, which throws the error is:

```
at resources.ExtentReporterNG.getReportObject(ExtentReporterNG.java:14)
```

and this is your project class, but from `ExtentReporterNG` name I guess you are using

https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java tool for generation the report.

And the error message:

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observer"
```

means that the issue is related to `io.reactivex.rxjava3` dependency.

And `extentreports-java` has this dependency in `pom.xml`.

https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java/blob/master/pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava3</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

---

**Conclusion**

I believe you have some other dependency in the project, which has another version of `io.reactivex` and the final resolved dependency doesn't contain `io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observer` class.

So, I suggest to add this dependency explicitly to the project pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava3</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

---

### Investigate Maven Dependency Conflicts

Add this plugin with next configuration to your pom (`<plugins>..</plugins>`)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <rules><DependencyConvergence/></rules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and execute:

```
mvn enforcer:enforce
```

This will print all potential dependency issues.

Look for lines with

```
io.reactivex
```

There are should be dependencies, which introduces the potential

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observer
```

error.

Comment: I have got 105 errors When trying to add this dependency

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is it possible to share the project pom.xml?

Comment: @mb13 I've added one more suggestion how to investigate the issue. Could you please give this a try and provide some results?